# Can I escape the pipe in specflow (or gherkin)

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I've got a specflow step table that I want to have the `|` (pipe) character as a part of the content.

Example:

```
Then the data should be
    | Field     | Value  |
    | SomeField | a|b|c  |
```

But this doesn't work. How can I escape the pipe character?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Bah. I can't believe I didn't find this earlier. You **CAN** escape a pipe with the backslash, but the specflow syntax highlighter gets confused by it.

```
Then the data should be
    | Field     | Value    |
    | SomeField | a\|b\|c  |
```

Comment: as a quick aside, if you're using SpecFlow, I highly recommend using SpecFlow Assist which is baked into the framework for mapping tables to your entity objects https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers