# How to escape '|' character in JBehave

Tags: java, gherkin, jbehave

I'm using **JBehave 4.0.5**

I need to escape the pipeline(|) from the JBehave tabular parameter verification.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960803/can-i-escape-the-pipe-in-specflow-or-gherkin) from Stack Overflow,  In Cucumber we can use '\|'  to escape the pipeline on tabular verification, but i couldn't find one for JBehave.

EX:

```
|Key 1      |Key 2  |
| |value 1| |value 2|
| |value 3| |value 4|
```

Comment: You can have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357982/how-use-pipe-character-inside-examples-table-of-behave-test-feature-file

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 like it says, its an ugly solution. Is there a official jBehave community site where i can post this issue ?

Comment: jBehave is a open source project and you can find your type of jBehave here https://github.com/jbehave?q=&type=source&language=  and log the issue.

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 The provided link is irrelevant, since it's about Python Behave, but this question is about Java JBehave

Answer (score 1):

JBehave allows to specify custom separators for ExamplesTable-s: [Tabular Parameters](https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html) > Specifying inlined separators.

```
{headerSeparator=!,valueSeparator=!}
!Key 1      !Key 2  !
! |value 1| !value 2!
! |value 3| !value 4!
```

Comment: I cannot change the Separators, because we have used '|'  in all our test scenarios.

Comment: @Aski you can change separator for one table only, all other tables are kept untouched